# spring oauth2 disabled form login

Tags: spring, forms, authentication

I use oauth2 in spring. However, the form login is not available any more. The urls ,"/j_spring_login" and "/j_spring_login_check" are not available.

springMVC.xml:

```
<!-- 自动扫描的包名 -->
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.sdp.hibernate.model.,com.sdp.hibernate.dao.,com.sdp.controller.,com.sdp.jsoncontroller."></context:component-scan>
<!-- 默认的注解映射的支持 -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- 视图解释类 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/> <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" 
    /> </bean> -->

<!-- 拦截器 <mvc:interceptors> <bean class="com.sdp.inteceptor.MyInteceptor" 
    /> </mvc:interceptors> -->
<!-- 对静态资源文件的访问 方案一 （二选一） <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> -->

<!-- 对静态资源文件的访问 方案二 （二选一） -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"
    cache-period="31556926" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"
    cache-period="31556926" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="dangerous" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="30" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate配置 -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.sdp.hibernate.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="velocityConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/templates/" />
    <!-- <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:velocity.properties"/> -->
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="output.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="input.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- oauth -->
<import resource="spring-servlet.xml" />
```

here is the spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" /> -->
</bean>
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>
<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.htm"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="oauthUserApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler">  
</bean> 
<http pattern="/oauth/**" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"  
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" auto-config="true">  
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>  
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>  
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>  
</http> 
<!--  
<http pattern="/v1/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
-->
<http pattern="/v1/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern='/v1/**' access="ROLE_USER"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern='/v1/protected/**' access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
         <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> 
 </http>
 <http pattern="/resources/**" auto-config="true"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern='/resources/**' access="ROLE_USER"/>         
 </http>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"  
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">  
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>  
</bean>  
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">  
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="client-details-user-service"/>  
</authentication-manager>  


<bean id="client-details-user-service" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">  
    <constructor-arg ref="client-details-service" />  
</bean> 

<oauth:client-details-service id="client-details-service">  

    <!-- Allow access to test clients -->  
    <oauth:client  
            client-id="353b302c44574f565045687e534e7d6a"  
            secret="286924697e615a672a646a493545646c"  
            authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token"  
            authorities="ROLE_USER"  
            access-token-validity="30000"  
            autoapprove = "true"
            refresh-token-validity="30000"  
            scope="read, write"
            />  

    <!-- Web Application clients -->  
    <oauth:client  
            client-id="7b5a38705d7b3562655925406a652e32"  
            secret="655f523128212d6e70634446224c2a48"  
            authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token"  
            authorities="ROLE_WEB"  
            access-token-validity="30000"  
            refresh-token-validity="30000"  
            />  

    <!-- iOS clients -->  
    <oauth:client  
            client-id="5e572e694e4d61763b567059273a4d3d"  
            secret="316457735c4055642744596b302e2151"  
            authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token"  
            authorities="ROLE_IOS"  
            access-token-validity="30000"  
            refresh-token-validity="30000"  
            />  

    <!-- Android clients -->  
    <oauth:client  
            client-id="302a7d556175264c7e5b326827497349"  
            secret="4770414c283a20347c7b553650425773"  
            authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token"  
            authorities="ROLE_ANDROID"  
            access-token-validity="30000"  
            refresh-token-validity="30000"  
            />  

</oauth:client-details-service>  

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <!-- <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" /> -->
    <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    <!--
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="marissa" password="koala" authorities="ROLE_TEST" />
            <user name="paul" password="emu" authorities="ROLE_GUEST" />
        </user-service>
        --> 

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a default implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="client-details-service" />
</bean>
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>
 <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
<!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />  
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: which version spring security are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: show your security configuration and login form.

Comment: i have given the mvc config and security config. I use default login form. As you can see, when I visist "/resources/**", the brower will redirect to "/spring_security_login", but "/spring_security_login" is not found.